# Individual objects in object array in swiftui not getting updated

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am working on an app and I am retrieving persons data from a server as shown in the PersonVM (person view model) as shown in the code snippet below. After getting the data from the server, I am making an additional request to retrieve extra data from a server to update each person in the persons array. However, the server request being made to retrieve extra data for each person only works for some of the persons in the persons array. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
   let id = UUID()
   var firstname: String
   var lastname: String
   var extraData: String
   var url: String
}

class PersonVM: ObservableObject {
  @Published var persons = [Person]()

  @MainActor
  public func getExtraData() async {
    // I get the persons data from a server
    // and I looping over each person making a 
    // network request to get extra data using person.url
    persons = data from server
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      persons.indices.forEach { index in 
        Task {
           let extraData = try await self.getExtraData(url:person[index].url)
           self.persons[index].extraData = extraData
        }
      }
    }

  }

struct PersonView: View {
    @Observable va personVM = PersonVM()

    var body: some View {
      List {
         ForEach(personVM.persons){
             person in
             PersonRowView(p: person)
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: "only works for some of the persons", what does that mean? Could you please clarify. And why are you mixing DispatchQueue.main.async and Task, it looks really strange?

Comment: you are mixing 2 very different concepts. You should watch WWDC tutorials Observable is a replacement for ObservableObject. Also never mix DispatchQueue and the new async await. I’m assuming you are copying and pasting code from different places. You should look at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

Comment: In SwiftUI the view struct is your view model already so use PersonView and declare @State var people as array of person structs and set it from a .task that uses async await to download, use a controller declared as environment if you like, see authorizationController to get the idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Reference Types***

**iOS 13-16 - `ObservableObject`**

You need a chain of tools to redraw a `View` with reference types.

A `class` that conforms to `ObservableObject` and has variables that are wrapped with `@Published`.

Then the instance of the `ObservableObject` must be wrapped in a `View` or `DynamicProperty` with one of the appropriate wrappers the wrapping must be done at every layer where you want to see changes.

The `ObservableObject` wrappers are

- `@StateObject` for initializing
- `@ObservedObject` for passing around
- `@EnvironmentObject` paired with the `ViewModifier` `.environmentObject()` to make the object available to child `View`s.

**iOS 17**

Introduced `@Observable` this is a macro.

You add this to the `class` (not a variable) something like `@Observable class Person {}`

This macro has the ability to redraw SwiftUI `View`s on its own. There is no need for any other wrappers to see changes.

Now to edit an `@Observable` object you need `@Bindable` in the `View`.

Here is a little curveball, pre-iOS 17 `@State` was typically reserved for value-types because it is not capable of seeing changes for Reference-types including `ObservableObject`.

It is now capable of being changes for `@Observable` types.

> Instantiate an observable model data type directly in a view using a State property. Share the observable model data with other views in the hierarchy without passing a reference using the Environment property wrapper.

Here are some references

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/model-data

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

If I assume `@Observable` is a typo because that line would not be allowed. Here is a working sample of what you code looks like.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PersonView: View {
    @StateObject private var personVM = PersonVM() //Observes changes to the `ObservableObject`
    //Keeps track of the task that is getting the extra data
    @State private var isGettingExtra: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button {
                isGettingExtra.toggle() //Use a `Button`, `.task` or any other interaction to trigger  `.task(id: isGettingExtra)`
            } label: {
                Text("Get extra data")
                    .overlay {
                        if isGettingExtra { //Show the user something while the task is running
                            ProgressView()
                        }
                    }
            }.task(id: isGettingExtra) {
                guard isGettingExtra else {
                    return
                }
                do {
                    try await personVM.getExtraData()
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                isGettingExtra = false
            }
            
            ForEach($personVM.persons){
                $person in
                PersonRowView(p: $person)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct PersonRowView: View {
    @Binding var p: Person //Binding is a two-way connection with value types.
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("first name", text: $p.firstname)
            Text("Extra Data \(p.extraData)")
        }
    }
}

class PersonVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var persons: [Person] = (0...10).map { n in
        Person(firstname: n.description, lastname: n.description, extraData: n.description, url: n.description)
    }
    
    
    public func getExtraData() async throws {
        // I get the persons data from a server
        // and I looping over each person making a
        // network request to get extra data using person.url

        persons = data from server

        //Don't mix `Task`, `async` or `await` with `DispatchQueue` the new Concurrency replaces older methodologies.
        for (index, _) in persons.enumerated(){
            let extraData = try await self.getExtraData(url:persons[index].url)
            self.persons[index].extraData = extraData
        }
    }
    func getExtraData(url: String) async throws -> String {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        return "\((0...100).randomElement()!)"
    }
}
```

If you are supporting iOS 17+ you should forget about `ObservableObject`s and just use `@Observable` correctly.

```
struct PersonView: View {
     @State private var personVM = PersonVM() //Use `@State` instead of `@StateObject`
     @State private var isGettingExtra: Bool = false
     var body: some View {
         List {
             Button {
                 isGettingExtra.toggle()
             } label: {
                 Text("Get extra data")
                     .overlay {
                         if isGettingExtra {
                             ProgressView()
                         }
                     }
             }.task(id: isGettingExtra) {
                 guard isGettingExtra else {
                     return
                 }
                 do {
                     try await personVM.getExtraData()
                 } catch {
                     print(error)
                 }
                 isGettingExtra = false
             }
             
             ForEach($personVM.persons){
                 $person in
                 PersonRowView(p: $person)
             }
         }
     }
 }

 @Observable
 class PersonVM {
     var persons: [Person] = (0...10).map { n in
         Person(firstname: n.description, lastname: n.description, extraData: n.description, url: n.description)
     }
     
     
     public func getExtraData() async throws {
         // I get the persons data from a server
         // and I looping over each person making a
         // network request to get extra data using person.url
         //persons = data from server
         for (index, _) in persons.enumerated(){
             let extraData = try await self.getExtraData(url:persons[index].url)
             self.persons[index].extraData = extraData
         }
     }
     func getExtraData(url: String) async throws -> String {
         try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
         return "\((0...100).randomElement()!)"
     }
 }
```

Comment: I replaced the ForEach with an OutlineGroup to display extra information in an expanded view, however when I scroll and scroll back up all the images disappear and only appear when I click anywhere on the screen. Not sure where the problem is.