# How to create 2-way binding between TextField and @Published property

Tags: swiftui

I am learning SwiftUI.

The app I'm working on has a UserSettings ObservableObject with a number of `@Published` integer properties. I'll talk about one of those properties, `userSettings.aspectWidth`, as an example of the problem I'm having.

In a content view, I need to create `TextField`s that bind to those `@Published` integer properties.

Since the properties are Ints, not Strings, I can't bind the `TextField` directly to the `@Published` property with `TextField("", text: $userSettings.aspectWidth)`.

That gives an error:

> /Users/duncan/Desktop/Development/AspectRatio/AspectRatio/ContentView.swift:43:55 Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Binding'

I **can** bind my `userSettings.aspectWidth` to the **value** of my text field, but that only creates a one-way binding. If the value in userSettings.aspectWidth changes, the TextField gets updated. However, if I edit the value in the TextField, it does not update the value in my @Published `userSettings.aspectWidth` property.

How do I create a 2-way binding between my @Published `userSettings.aspectWidth` property and my `TextField`?

Comment: Just add a $ to userSettings

Comment: @loremipsum that doesn't work. If I create a TextField with `TextField("", value: $userSettings.aspectWidth, format: .number)`, it displays the value, but does not update it if I edit the `TextField`.

Comment: Something else is wrong then. Binding is by definition a two way connection Apple doesn’t create one way Binding

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211411/problems-trying-to-use-environment-with-binding/76213700#76213700) is a long post I wrote for another experienced developer part 2 may shed some light.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76889045/individual-objects-in-object-array-in-swiftui-not-getting-updated/76889562#76889562) is likely your issue.

Comment: When I enter new data into the textField and press enter it logs an error to the console (iOS 17 simulator) '-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:] perform input operation requires a valid sessionID` –

Comment: There looks like there's a lot of speculation about what the setup really is here. Can you include a [mre] so that the setup is clear?

Comment: `ObservableObject` is not the right tool for user settings, that's designed for an async Combine pipeline. See `@AppStorage` (or `@SceneStorage`) for user settings.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

It occurs to me that perhaps the behavior you’re seeing is that the `TextField` does not update its text when it has keyboard focus (is first responder) and its `Binding`’s value is changed by something else. To fix that, you can tell the `TextField` to end editing before changing the value externally. There is SwiftUI API to control focus, but the easiest way is to just fall back to UIKit like this:

```
Button("Reset to 100") {
    // Defocus (resign first responder) any text field currently
    // focused.
    Button("Reset to 100") {
        for scene in UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes {
            (scene as? UIWindowScene)?.keyWindow?.endEditing(true)
        }
        settings.aspectWidth = 100
    }
    settings.aspectWidth = 100
}
```

### ORIGINAL

If your deployment target is iOS 15 or later, you can use [`TextField.init(_:value:format:prompt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:format:prompt:)-3fh51) to supply a [`ParseableFormatStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/parseableformatstyle) that converts between the value type (in your case, `Int`) and `String`. Try this:

```
TextField("aspectWidth", value: $settings.aspectWidth, format: .number)
```

If you want to deploy back to iOS 13, you can use [`TextField.init(_:value:formatter:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield/init(_:value:formatter:)-4013v) to supply a [`Formatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/formatter) that does the conversion. `Formatter` is an older, less type-safe API (it is from Objective-C and predates the Swift language entirely). You’d want to use a [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter) in your example.

Here’s a complete working example:

```
class UserSettings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var aspectWidth: Int = 100
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var settings = UserSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("aspectWidth = \(settings.aspectWidth)")
            Button("Reset to 100") { 
                settings.aspectWidth = 100
            }
            TextField("aspectWidth", value: $settings.aspectWidth, format: .number)
                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

If specifying a format doesn’t work for you, then you need to edit your question to include more of your code.

Comment: He is likely not observing the observable object in the secondary place. In the comments he states that he can edit the text field but doesn’t see the changes.

Comment: That may be, but my answer directly addresses the code and error message he included in his post.

Comment: Agreed, his comments say he has tried this solution he is missing key info in the question.

Comment: When I enter new data into the textField and press enter it logs an error to the console (iOS 17 simulator) '-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID`

Comment: Rob, I was in fact having problems with first responder. UIApplication.shared.keyWindow is deprecated in iOS 13 however since it doesn't work with multiple screens. Is there a solution for multiple screens?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to rob's answer, if the deployment target must be iOS 13 and you want to avoid the `Formatter` you can place a custom `Binding` between the `@Published` property and the text field to do the `String / Int` conversion

```
...
var body: some View {
    let stringIntBinding = Binding(
        get: { String(settings.aspectWidth) },
        set: { settings.aspectWidth = Int($0) ?? 100 }
    )
    
   ...
   TextField("aspectWidth", text: stringIntBinding)
   
}
```